# Javascript log and console

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out this simple snippet.
What is it supposed to output?

```
var scope = "global";
    function f() {
        console.log(scope);
        var scope = "local";
        console.log(scope);
    }
```

Comment: `console.log` function is printing stuff in Browser Console (Ctrl+K or Ctrl+Shift+i)

Comment: ahh, it won't output anything at all - since you never invoke function f, you just declare it

Comment: It doesn't output anything. You need to add `f()` so the function is actually called.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```js
var scope = "global";
    function f() {
        console.log(scope);
        var scope = "local";
        console.log(scope);
    }
```

Output:

```js
undefined
```

But if you add `f()` to the end of your code:

```js
undefined
local
```

just try it out!

```js
var scope = "global";
    function f() {
        console.log(scope);
        var scope = "local";
        console.log(scope);
    }

f()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `f()` you will log out `undefined` and `"local"`.

This happens because of how function (local) scope works, it will first "read" the function and because variable "scope" is defined within the function it will treat all instances (within the function) of variable "scope" as local scope.

You then get undefined because of that local scope variable not having been defined at the first console.log call.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

When you call `f()` the expected output is

```
undefined
local
```

Why? Because there is something called [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Your code effectively becomes:

```
var scope = "global";
function f() {
    // variable declaration has been hoisted
    var scope;
    console.log(scope); // undefined
    scope = "local";
    console.log(scope); // local
}
```